# Alerting in splunk for different thresholds

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, dashboard, splunk, splunk-query

Can we trigger alerts in splunk for different values of threshold. I mean if threshold value is 90 then it should trigger an alert for slack and if the threshold is some other value like 120 then it should trigger some email alert. Is such a condition possible in splunk using a single alert. If yes then how?

Answer (score 1):

Splunk alerts have only one set of actions they can take whenever the alert is triggered.  Go to https://ideas.splunk.com to make a case for different alert levels.